# Google Play Savegames - Cover Image size

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Does anyone know which dimensions are needed for the `cover image` of a `snapshot` for `Google Play savegames`?

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames.html#cover_images) I only found the information about the size (not bigger than 800KB), but not which resolution the image should have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't also see documentations or articles regarding the exact resolution the image should have. I guess you're the one to specify the `coverImage.height` and `coverImage.width` as long as it doesn't exceed the 800 KB size limit. You may refer with this [sample JSON template for a snapshot object](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/snapshots#resource-representations). Here's also a sample [code](https://github.com/xshengcn/Nice/blob/e043cf11e9e49a051d8dca798ab5a6fcb095fef9/app/src/main/java/com/github/niceapp/common/CoverImage.java) from GitHub.

```
public interface CoverImage {
    int WIDTH = 600;
    int HEIGHT = 338;

    float RATIO = (WIDTH * 1.0f) / HEIGHT;
}
```

Hope this helps!